# PHP connection to IBM DB2 database columns truncate

Tags: php, db2, driver

We can get the data from DB2 database table ussing IBM DB2 connector 2.0.8 for PHP.
The problem is that the column size is 10 but when the content of the row contains n tilde or some special charater the row is truncate when we try to get it.
I think this kind of special characters occupies double space instead of single one and that's the reason because the string is truncate at the end.
When we connect via DBeaver client, the row is getting right and it shows complete in the results screen without truncate.

Could be a problem with the connector?

I try to set diferent configuration on the PHP.ini file and set some options on the connectios but nothing works.

Comment: It is correct that some characters need more than one byte of storage. This is not a fault. You should ensure that your php code understands and accomodates the encoding of your Db2 database. You should be using v2.1.7 of the wrapper for the Db2-driver (along with the latest clidriver) to get all the fixes.  In short, you cannot configure around this, you have to fix your code, and ensure you are on latest versions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.